# Tensorflow Object Detection: Missing Metrics "oid_challenge_object_detection_metrics"

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets

I'm having problems training and evaluating the Open Images dataset, because the "**oid_challenge_object_detection_metrics**" is not defined.

It is defined in the documentation:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/evaluation_protocols.md

However, the code does not exist in **[eval_util.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/eval_util.py)**, which only defines the processing logic for "coco_detection_metrics" and "coco_mask_metrics".

Thus, when I run object_detection/model_main.py, it terminates with the error:

```
File "object_detection/eval_util.py", line 650, in get_eval_metric_ops_for_evaluators
    'Found {} in the evaluation metrics'.format(metric))
ValueError: The only evaluation metrics supported are "coco_detection_metrics" and "coco_mask_metrics". Found oid_challenge_object_detection_metrics in the evaluation metrics
```

It is defined in my pipeline config:

```
eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "oid_challenge_object_detection_metrics"
  num_examples: 8000
  max_evals: 10
}
```

I found a file under **[metrics/oid_od_challenge_evaluation.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/metrics/oid_od_challenge_evaluation.py)**, but I am not sure how to integrate it into the eval_util.py.

How do I properly run the model training and evaluation? Thank you.